# How to apply validation for the Fetched data in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, for-loop

I have a program which output's a 3 group of Fields from the stored data in the database.
I able to print it using the for loop but the validation is only for the 1st group field and the other rest 2 group of Fields are not validated.

Below is the code and screen shot of my progam.

*edit.php*

```
<?php for($q=0;$q<count($arr_search['response'][0]['add_info']);$q++){?>

<div class="present_fields_1">
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Type of work:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control" style="width: 70%;">
      <option value="Audit Report">Audit Report</option>
      <option value="ITR filing">ITR filing</option>
      <option value="VAT Filing">VAT Filing</option>
      <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
      <option value="Registration">Registration</option>
      <option value="Certification">Certification</option>
      <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Status:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="status" name="status[]" class="form-control" style="width: 70%;">
      <option value="<?php echo $arr_search['response'][0]['add_info'][$q]['status']; ?>"><?php echo $arr_search['response'][0]['add_info'][$q]['status']; ?></option>
      <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
      <option value="Work in process">Work in process</option>
      <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<!--date-->
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label" style="margin-left:28.5%;">DATE:</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control datepicker p" id="date[]" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $arr_search['response'][0]['add_info'][$q]['date']; ?>"   type="text" readonly style="width: 70%;">
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Comment:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="commentss" name="comment[]" value="<?php echo $arr_search['response'][0]['add_info'][$q]['comment']; ?>" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" style="width: 70%;" >

  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="remove_field_pre1" style="">
 <img src="images/del24.png">
</a>

</div>


<?php  }?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#status").click(function () {

            if ($("#status").val() == "Completed") {
                $("#commentss").attr("required", "required");
            }
            else
              $("#commentss").attr("required", false);
        });
});
</script>
```

As you can see that, the last part of the code i.e, Javascript is only apply to the 1st group and not the remaining part of the code.

This is the ScreenShot [image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
$("#status").click(function () {
```

here you are using `#` ie Id selectors, which are unique in a page. Instead use `.` selectors and iterate the object using `$.each()` and check if every element is valid or not.

Comment: Or change the ID to something unique (so the HTML haven't any errors) ... `name="status<?php echo $q; ?>[]"` could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="status<?php echo $q?>"
<input id="commentss<?php echo $q?>"

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
  $("#status"+i).click(function () {

        if ($("#status"+i).val() == "Completed") {
            $("#commentss"+i).attr("required", "required");
        }
        else
          $("#commentss"+i).attr("required", false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you briefly explain why this code works?

Comment: @Asmin . The javascript is not working .The validation of first assignment is also not working.